# S3 error undefined (reading byteLength) for AWS AMPLIFY

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I keep getting a
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')`
Error when using AWS with Amplify.

It looks like the s3 bucket permissions were not created properly when I added the s3 through the Amplify CLI.

When I add the sample s3 bucket policy from https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/storage/getting-started/q/platform/js/

It still does not work.

```
AWSS3Provider - get signed url error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
```

My Code to call it:

```
const res = await Storage.get("test.json");
```

This includes any `Storage.list`, `Storage.put` commands.

[image]

This leads me to believe it has trouble getting the key from storage. I have done it all through the cli which is puzzling.

Comment: you could be more specific, what permissions are missing? where/when do you get the exception?  How did you come to a conclusion the exception is caused by lack of permissions? The policies mentioned are to be attached to the IAM cognito roles, not the S3 bucket

Comment: I was thinking it was permissions because i had a basic example and it didnt work. I will post more details.

Answer (score 0):

> When I add the sample s3 bucket policy 
> Question is: What do I add for the principal for an authenticated user? Does anyone have a sample?

The policies mentioned are to be attached to the IAM cognito roles  `Auth_Role` and `Unauth_Role` (or however are the roles for the cognito users named) not the S3 bucket. Then the principal is the IAM role itself.

In theory you may attach the defined policies to the S3 bucket and define the principals as the Cognito roles for the authenticated and unauthenticated users

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Changing the authentication rules on the bucket, it solved my problem. In the amplify studio, I went to `Storage` and changed `Authentication Rules` so Guest Users could upload to the bucket.